Debugging from Virtual Box VM to Bluestacks in Host Machine
I have Windows 11 in my host with Bluestacks 5 installed and ADB enabled
I have a virtual machine (Virtual Box) with windows 10 running Visual Studio which needs to connect to Bluestacks using "adb connect"
I can´t connect using adb connect <Host-ip>:5555
In Bluestacks Config in the host, it says 127.0.0.1:5555
I tried in the Host using adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555 and it worked. But it did not work with adb connect <Host-ip>:5555
Any workaround for connecting to "127.0.0.1:5555" in the VM?
